# Spivak Calculus Chapter 3 Question 6

Tags: calculus

> If $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are distinct numbers, find a polynomial function $f_i$ of degree $n−1$ which is $1$ at $x_i$ and $0$ at $x_j$ for $j\not=i$.

Forgive my complete ignorance, but I do not understand what this question is asking. Can someone please explain the following basics to me or suggest where I might learn to comprehend such questions?

**My attemp**: The $i$ in $f_i$ serves only to distinguish $f_i$ as the polynomial function in question from some random polynomial function. It does not mean $f(x_i)$, nor does it have any relationship to $x_i$, but rather there is some value for $f_i$ of any $x$. If so, why not just call it $f$. If otherwise, what does it mean?

What is the significance of "degree $n-1$"? Must the $x_1,...,x_n$ be ordered such that $x_i$ can be found from any $x$?

How can I learn to comprehend these questions? Should I be studying at a lower level? I was top in my calculus class at the University of Illinois in the 1980s, but I cannot even figure out what this question is asking.

As an aside, where can I learn to use the math editor on this site?

Comment: About learning to use the math editor, here's a useful link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: There will be different polynomial functions for each $x_i$.  $f_i$ is the polynomial function corresponding to $x_i$.  For example, if the points are $1, 2, 3$ then $f_2$ is the polynomial where $f_2(2) = 1$ and $f_2(1)=f_2(3)=0$.  Since there are three points, $n=3$ and the degree of $f_2$ is 2.

Comment: Useful reference: [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Note this is just an outgrowth of the fact that two points determine a line, three non-colinear points determine a parabola, etc.

Comment: There are some missing universal quantifiers that readers are assumed to fill in. See if this helps. Instead of $n$ (what's missing is saying at the beginning "for each positive integer $n$ let $\ldots"),$ use $5,$ and instead of $i$ (what's missing is saying "for each $i$ in the set $\{1, \, 2, \, \ldots, \, n\}$ find $\ldots")$ use $3.$ Then you have $5$ numbers (all different from each other) and you're supposed to find a polynomial, which we'll denote by $f_3,$ of algebraic degree $4$ such that $f_3(x_1) = 0$ and $f_3(x_2) = 0$ and $f_3(x_3) = 1$ and $f_3(x_4) = 0$ and $f_3(x_5) = 0.$

Comment: About your attempt, the function does have a relationship with  $i$. A way of writing $f_i$ in a way that makes this clearer is $$ f_i(x_j)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1, {\ \ \ } i=j \\ 
0, {\ \ \ }i \neq j
\end{array}
\right.$$

Answer (score 3):

> Preliminaries

Degree means the order of the polynomial, e.g. the function $g(x) = x^2 - 3x + 2$ is degree $2$ (the highest power of $x$). Note the function $g$ can also be written as

$$
g(x) = \underbrace{(x - 1)(x - 2)}_{\text{2 factors}}
$$

A couple of things to realize here

1. The number of factors is the order of the polynomial
2. $g(1) = 0$ and $g(2) = 0$, so at least we understand now how to get one the requirements of the problems solved, the other one is easy, it is just a matter of dividing by the right number

> Now the problem

Consider an arbitrary $i$ and define the function

$$
h(x) = (x - x_1) (x - x_2) \cdots (x - x_{i-1})(x - x_{i + 1}) \cdots (x - x_n) \tag{1}
$$

This function has $n-1$ factors (note that the factor $x - x_i$ is missing). Since this function is tied to the selection of $i$ it makes sense to label it with this value, so let's rename this function $h_i$

$$
h_i(x) = (x - x_1) (x - x_2) \cdots (x - x_{i-1})(x - x_{i + 1}) \cdots (x - x_n) \tag{2}
$$

Note that this function satisfies

$$
h_i(x_i) = (x_i - x_1) (x_i - x_2) \cdots (x_i - x_{i-1})(x_i - x_{i + 1}) \cdots (x_i - x_n) \not = 0
$$

since all numbers are distinct. However if you evaluate this function at $x = x_j$ one of the terms must be $(x_j - x_j) = 0$ so the function will vanish

$$
h_i(x_j) = (x_j - x_1) (x_j - x_2) \cdots (x_j - x_{i-1})(x_j - x_{i + 1}) \cdots (x_j - x_n)  = 0 ~~~ i \not = j
$$

Now define the function

$$
f_i(x) = \frac{h_i(x)}{h_i(x_i)}
$$

and that's it